# Vue clickable row and href conflict

Tags: vue.js, href, tr

Sorry. An upside-down question. I have this table. That is clickable through iWasClicked function, but I also have the last td with clickable images (href). I want the last td to be only clickable through the images(href). Now, it triggers both. The href link and the iWasClicked from the tr.

```
<tr
          class="bg-gray-100 text-dark text-center cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-300"
          v-for="currentView in getOrganizationsDashboard().projects"
          :key="currentView.id"
          @click="iWasClicked(currentView.projectName)"
        >
          <td class="px-4 py-3 border-b-2 border-dark">
            <!-- {{ showProjectSuccessRunPercentage(currentView)}} -->
            <img
              class="w-10 inline-block align-middle"
              :src="showProjectSuccessRunPercentage(currentView)"
              alt="Organization Icon"
            />
          </td>
          <td class="px-4 py-3 border-b-2 border-dark">
            {{ currentView["projectName"] }}
          </td>
          <td class="px-4 py-3 border-b-2 border-dark">
            <a
              class=" "
              :href="
                'https://xxx.us/org/' + currentView['projectName']
              "
              target="_blank"
              ><img
                class="inline-block w-10"
                alt=""
                src="../assets/img/myLogo.svg"
            /></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop the click event from bubbling up and triggering a click on the `tr`, which you can do like this:

`<a @click="$event.stopPropagation()"</a>`

Comment: Also worked. Not sure what's the difference between this and calling " @click.stop" ? Both seem working for me. Thanks alot and sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a
  class=" "
  :href="'https://xxx.us/org/' + currentView['projectName']"
  target="_blank"
  @click.stop
  >
    <img class="inline-block w-10"
         alt=""
         src="../assets/img/myLogo.svg"/>
</a>
```

Comment: BTW the difference between Brother Woodrow and mine is that I'm using the vue event modifiers which is more simple and readable while he is using vanilla javascript. You cannot go wrong with both approach

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to use the provided Vue event modifiers for `@click` which is `.stop`. Like what [Brother Woodrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67295039/11138585) answered, this will also stop the click event's propagation.

```
<tr @click.stop="iWasClicked(currentView.projectName)">
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes thank you, but a small edit. I should place it in the td i want to stop on click, rather than the whole tr. Thanks again !